# FME and elasticsearch

Tags: geojson, fme-form, elasticsearch

We are developing a system to disseminate information about roadkills. The source data comes from three different databases. We have set up a FME project which pulls geojson from the source databases, joins them according too a set of business rules and then exports them to a front-end database.

We are currently exporting our data to a [PostGIS](http://postgis.net/) database. FME does this very nicely. Now my colleague suggests we use [Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/) since this will make the presentation of our data in [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) less complicated. Elasticsearch evidently indexes geojson on the fly.

We are using FME version 15.0. How can I write the data to Elasticsearch from FME? Which writer should I use?

Comment: Postgres as of 9.1 has supported JSON as a native datatype and as of 9.3 there is JSONB, which allows for proper indexing of JSON as well. Could you explain how you want to present data in Leaflet that makes Elastic Search preferable to Postgres?

Comment: You can't get data out of Postgres without an API. That's why Elasticsearch would be preference: a built in web-accessible API.

Comment: @alexgleith. Getting data out of Postgres in JSON(B) format could be done with less than 5 lines of something like nodejs, which may be less work than moving everything to ElasticSearch -- an API sure, but hardly heavy weight. ElasticSearch is great, but designed to solve different issues than easily getting JSON to Leaflet, I would argue. This is not clear from the question.

Comment: See tweet https://twitter.com/FMEEvangelist/status/590518826225246208 (PR61198) look out at the end of September 2015 when 2016 betas become nightly http://downloads.safe.com/fme/beta/whatsnew_sp.txt

Comment: You could also export data direct to GeoJSON on the server. To answer @JohnBarça, I find that having an overhead of server-side code is sometimes intimidating. Unless, of course, you already have a web-app framework. Many of my web-apps are pure client-side and having an API to work with where I don't develop it is nice and keeps things simple.

Comment: @alexgleith. Fair enough. I do a lot of Leaflet/CartoDB these days, so am certainly a fan of fat clients, data on cloud, and no thinking about the server side if you don't need to. But, ultimately, it is what you are used to -- I find NodeJS or Python on a server vastly preferable to the black box, spaghetti of FME, but that is entirely my own, possibly highly dubious, opinion.

Comment: What's funny here is that we did a webinar once that used roadkill data from the city of Vancouver as an example - and got complaints that it was in bad taste! Even though it's real data that depicts a real issue. So whatever you do with your data - make sure you do it tastefully ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GDAL/OGR supports [Elasticsearch](http://www.gdal.org/drv_elasticsearch.html), which means that FME could support it reasonably easily.

I reckon you might like to hit up the FME people on Twitter and put in a request. Try Mark Ireland [@FMEEvangelist](https://twitter.com/FMEEvangelist) or Dale Lutz [@DaleAtSafe](https://twitter.com/daleatsafe) and Don Murray [@DonAtSafe](https://twitter.com/donatsafe).

But anyway, you could use a FME script to prepare your data, then write it to a temporary file, and then use Python to write, either directly (tricky but solid), or using OGR (easy, less flexible), to Elasticsearch. I'd implement that, and then contact the FME guys and tell them to hurry up and implement an Elasticsearch writer!

Comment: Add your feature requests to the 2016 FME trello board https://trello.com/b/FddU9irV/fme-2016-desktop-engine-enhancements

Comment: Tweet sent https://twitter.com/mapperz/status/590309752334376960

Answer (score 3):

Give this recent talk by Paul Ramsey a view:

http://blog.cleverelephant.ca/2015/03/magical-postgis.html

He suggests that the PostgreSQL Full Text search make ElasticSearch unnecessary...

Something to consider anyway...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think we could implement this in FME pretty easily. I've filed an enhancement request with our developers and we'll see what they say. If you contact our support team (http://safe.com/support) and let them know you are interested then they can add your contact details to the request. The reference number is PR#61198

Also, do please add it to the Trello board that Mapperz mentions, as the more users who upvote it on there, the more likely it is that we will implement it.

In the meantime, I took a quick look and it says ElasticSearch is accessible through an API in JSON format. So why not write the data as JSON and use the API to upload it?

I can think of a few ways:

- Convert your data to JSON with a transformer like the JSONTemplater and then upload it with a HTTPCaller transformer.
- Write the data with a JSON Writer, then put the HTTPCaller in a second workspace.
- Write the data with a JSON Writer, then use a Python shutdown script to upload the data through a call to their API

Comment: Message sent to the support team. Also signed up on Trello, but I do not have the sufficient access to make suggestions there yet.

Comment: I've never thought about using FME to upload to an API using JSON! Very interesting...

Comment: @ragnvald: If you add a comment to the "Other Items" list in Trello I think someone in the dev team with permission will upgrade it to a full suggestion.

Comment: Support for this planned for FME2016.1